# iText 7 HtmlConverter.convertToPdf is breaking

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Hi I'm trying to convert a HTML String to pdf using itext 7 (latest version 7.1.15) available in maven repo.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;

public class PdfHtmlResponsiveDesign 

{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        String htmlSource = "<h1>aaa</h1>";
        File pdfDest = new File("C:\\Users\\acme\\Desktop\\tester\\itext7.pdf");
        // pdfHTML specific code
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        converterProperties.setBaseUri("");
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlSource,
                                   new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), converterProperties);
    }
}
```

But this simple code is throwing errors. This was working with itext 5.x.
Any pointers to find the issue would be extremely helpful.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/kernel/counter/event/IMetaInfo
    at com.pegado.qpguard.demo.PdfHtmlResponsiveDesign.main(PdfHtmlResponsiveDesign.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.kernel.counter.event.IMetaInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

**Note:**

Itext 7 Version 7.1.15

html2pdf Version 3.0.4

**Additional Info**

If I change the version of itext to 7.1.14 the same code gives me another error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/itextpdf/layout/renderer/FlexContainerRenderer
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.util.WaitingInlineElementsHelper.flushHangingLeaves(WaitingInlineElementsHelper.java:196)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.DivTagWorker.processEnd(DivTagWorker.java:97)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.HTagWorker.processEnd(HTagWorker.java:67)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:345)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:338)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:338)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:253)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:78)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:325)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:139)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:127)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:104)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:92)
    at com.pegado.qpguard.demo.PdfHtmlResponsiveDesign.main(PdfHtmlResponsiveDesign.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.FlexContainerRenderer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 14 more
```

Thank you

Comment: Finally, I had to do this with PdfBox

Answer (score 2):

If iText 5 user needed only one jar to do all the magic, iText 7, on the contrary, splits different functionality into separate modules. One should have:

- a dependency on `html2pdf` (separate project) to harness html-to-pdf conversion functionality;
- a dependency on `layout` (separate module of iTextCore project) to have means to layout element to PDF;
- a dependency on `kernel` (separate module of iTextCore project) for some core stuff (in your case, `IMetaInfo`, which is internally used while considering the fact, whether any license is loaded).

So there were no issue with iTextcore 7.1.15 + pdfHTML 3.0.4, you just needed to add one more dependency. As for iTextcore 7.1.14 + pdfHTML 3.0.4: they are indeed incompatible, more precisely, flex elements are already supported in 3.0.4 on pdfHTML level, but not yet at layout level. The compatibility matrix could be found here: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/compatibility-matrix

Answer (score 1):

This problem is definitely not related to the iText itself. I wasn't able to reproduce this problem with Itext 7.1.15 and html2pdf 3.0.4.
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception is typically thrown when there are problems with classpath. see [Why am I getting a NoClassDefFoundError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java) . I can suggest to clean your .m2 folder or try to reload projects in intellij.